# Why is my site consistently showing not found?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, perl, webserver, virtualmin

I recently connected migrated my website from Bluehost to a private server, and I am having trouble with the configuration of my apache server. No matter what page I attempt to visit on my site, it displays a 404 this url is not found on this server error.

My site is written in both perl and php. Mostly perl. Would a perl version mismatch between my old server and my new server make the not found error appear? I would think that would cause a 500 server error.

What am I doing wrong? What do I change in order to make it work?

I have played around with the part of my httpd.conf file that controls my website.

My site is behind a reverse proxy that points to my backend server running the site at 333.333.333.333/test

Here it is:

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1001"
ServerName test.example.org
ServerAlias www.test.example.org
ServerAlias mail.test.example.org
ServerAlias webmail.test.example.org
ServerAlias admin.test.example.org
DocumentRoot /home/theuser/public_html/testrbs
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/test.example.org_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test.example.org_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/theuser/public_html/test/cgi-bin
DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory "/home/theuser/public_html/test">
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/theuser/public_html/test/cgi-bin">
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having a misconfiguration higher up in the httpd.conf which dissallowed most of what I was doing, so the settings that I showed which I was changing weren't making a difference because Apache didn't look at them.

I uninstalled Virtualmin which was controlling the conf file, then I set Apache up manually and carefully. Now it is working.